# Studying a family of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose a sequence$\displaystyle (u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ as:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, u_{n+2}=(n+1)u_{n+1}+u_n$$

$\{x_0=1; x_1=0;\forall n\in \mathbb{N},x_{n+2}=(n+1)x_{n+1}+x_n $

and

$\{y_0=0;y_1=1; \forall n\in \mathbb{N},y_{n+2}=(n+1)y_{n+1}+y_n$

and I already proved that we can write $u_n=\alpha x_n+ \beta y_n$ with $(\alpha ; \beta)\in \mathbb{R}$.
but I'm stuck with proving that (By supposing that $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converge) :

1. $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty}{nu_n=0}$ .
2. What is the limit of $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: The name in english is "Sequence". Series is a sum (usually infinite)

Answer (score 1):

If $u_n\to\ell$ then $u_{n+2}\to\ell$ hence $(n+1)u_{n+1}=u_{n+2}-u_n\to\ell-\ell=0$, which implies that $u_{n+1}\to0$, that is, $\ell=0$.

To sum up, if $(u_n)$ converges, then the limit is $0$.

One should keep in mind though that in many cases (for example if $u_0$ and $u_1$ have the same sign and are not both zero) the sequence $(u_n)$ diverges because $|u_n|\to+\infty$.